# Java Game Dev: Checking if player is in-between two y coords

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection

I'm making a game [image: looks like this] with Slick2D. When a player get's under a window with an enemy in it, they can shoot, and points will be added. I have every mechanic completed besides the shooting one. Here is my "plan" on how it'll work.

When the player gets below the window(which the program picks up on via y coordinate) and fires, points will be added to a counter.

How can I get my program to realize that the player is indeed below a window?

Thanks, and here's my PlayState code.

```
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.transition.FadeInTransition;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.transition.FadeOutTransition;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Timer;

public class PlayState extends BasicGameState{

int stateID = -1;

int w = SwegBoi.WIDTH;
int h = SwegBoi.HEIGHT;
static int enemylocation;
float s = SwegBoi.SCALE;
Image playbackground;
Image swegboiplayer;
Image quit;
Image enemy1;
Image enemy2;
float playery;
int score = 0;

final static Random ran = new Random();
static Timer tm = new Timer();
static long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

public static void main(String args){

}


public PlayState(int stateID){
    this.stateID = stateID;
}

@Override
public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)
        throws SlickException {
    swegboiplayer = new Image("resources/swegboibackgun.png");
    playbackground = new Image("resources/playstatebackground.png");
    quit = new Image("resources/mainmenuquit.png");
    enemy1 = new Image("resources/enemy1.png");
    enemy2 = new Image("resources/enemy1.png");

    tm.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            enemylocation = ran.nextInt(4) + 1;
        }
    }, 1, 2000);


}




@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g)
        throws SlickException {
    playbackground.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
    playbackground.draw(0, 0, s*10);
    quit.draw((w-175*s),5 *s,s/2);

    if(enemylocation==1){
        enemy1.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
        enemy1.draw(200,170,s*10);
    }
    if(enemylocation==2){
        enemy1.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
        enemy1.draw(200,360,s*10);  
    }
    if(enemylocation==3){
        enemy1.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
        enemy1.draw(950,170,s*10);
    }
    if(enemylocation==4){
        enemy1.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
        enemy1.draw(950,360,s*10);
    }

    swegboiplayer.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
    swegboiplayer.draw((w*s)/2-(playery*s), 450*s, s*5);

    g.drawString("Alpha V0.1",6,6);
}



@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)
        throws SlickException {
    Input input = gc.getInput();
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){playery += 17;}
    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){playery -= 17;}
    int mouseX = input.getMouseX();
    int mouseY = input.getMouseY();

    if(mouseHover(mouseX,mouseY,(w-175*s),5*s,quit.getHeight()/2,quit.getWidth()) == true){
        if(input.isMousePressed(0)){
            sbg.enterState(SwegBoi.MAINMENUSTATE,new FadeOutTransition(), new FadeInTransition());
        }
        quit = new Image("resources/mainmenuquithover.png");
    }else{
        quit = new Image("resources/mainmenuquit.png");

    }}



@Override
public int getID() {
    return stateID;
}


public boolean mouseHover(int mouseX, int mouseY, float x, float y, float height, float width){
    if((mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x + width && mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y + height)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

}}

Comment: Well if the user is under a window with an enemy he is also under the enemy inside that window. Just check if the user is under that enemy. In this case, that would mean that he is between the X position of the enemy and X + width of the enemy. Now, you can further refine that notion of "between" by deciding exactly how accurate you want it to be (i.e. if the right corner of your hero sprite enters the left corner, does it count ?)

Comment: +1 for the 8-bit graphics

Comment: @Brad I would say that this actually has little to do with Java specifically.  The kind of calculation you're looking for would be conceptually the same in any language, and is more a matter of mathematics understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. Every time you move, check if you are in a range of an enemy x position and determine if shooting should be enabled or disabled. Define some kind of range for each enemies X position.

```
   private void checkShootStatus()
   {
      // Calculate image bounds X Position + width
      float swegboiplayerEndBound = swegboiplayer.getX() + swegboiplayer.getWidth();
      float enemyEndBound = enemy.getX() + enemy.getWidth();

      // Check enemy 1
      if (swegboiplayerEndBound > enemy.getX() && swegboiplayer.getX() < enemyEndBound)
      {
         canShoot = true;
      }
      else
      {
         canShoot = false;
      }
   }
```

Since you cannot get the x location of an image, create a wrapper class to track the x/y positions of the player and enemy.

```
public class Player extends Image
{
   private String image;
   private float x = 0;
   private float y = 0;

   public Player(String image) throws SlickException
   {
      super(image);

      this.setImage(image);
   }

   public float getY()
   {
      return y;
   }

   public void setY(float y)
   {
      this.y = y;
   }

   public String getImage()
   {
      return image;
   }

   public void setImage(String image)
   {
      this.image = image;
   }

   public float getX()
   {
      return x;
   }

   public void setX(float x)
   {
      this.x = x;
   }
}
```

Enemy

```
public class Enemy extends Image
{
   private String image;
   private int x;
   private int y;

   public Enemy(String image) throws SlickException
   {
      super(image);

      this.setImage(image);
   }

   public int getY()
   {
      return y;
   }

   public void setY(int y)
   {
      this.y = y;
   }

   public String getImage()
   {
      return image;
   }

   public void setImage(String image)
   {
      this.image = image;
   }

   public int getX()
   {
      return x;
   }

   public void setX(int x)
   {
      this.x = x;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a question. How would I check if the player x position is "near" the enemy's x position? Sorry, I'm kind of a noob at Java.

Comment: Thank you so much. I haven't tested it, but please explain to what "EndBound" means?

Also, everything is right besides the posX. I'll make a variable for that :)

Comment: Or can't you use getWidth and getHeight?

Comment: Updated with a visual. Visuals are always better! Hope it helps and good luck learning java!

Comment: I don't think the code is working... I used a g.drawString method to print out wether it is working or not. If he is in the enemy range it SHOULD say "YAY IT WORKS!" if not, "Aww..." Here's my code:http://pastebin.com/20970Wd2

Comment: Can you use a System.out.pritnln("YAY IT WORKS"), just to ensure it isn't an issue with g.drawString()?

Comment: I did, and my console was filled with "YAY IT WORKS"

Any ideas?

Comment: Change your getHeight() calls into getting the X Position of the image. POSITION of X.
Positions have X & Y

Comment: Position of X would just be X or would some math be involved with Y? "Positions have X & Y"

Comment: Here's my code now: http://pastebin.com/qNY9Y8tM   

Same issue. My console is filled with "YAY IT WORKS!"

Comment: Check the update code above. I *think* that will work. I checked out the java docs to get the appropriate method calls.

Comment: My console is being filled with "YAY IT WORKS" and then the game crashed. I'll provide my ENTIRE code now along with the error code. http://pastebin.com/G9wqtDU4

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but check your if statements. Needs to  be "==" not "=".

Comment: Post you SwegBoi class as well please

Comment: Still having my console spammed. Even when I go out of the map. I'm thinking it may be a bracket error or something of that nature. By the way, I had to remove the ending SlickException. Eclipse wasn't letting me use it.

Comment: Can you post the entire project somewhere? it'll be much easier to help if I can actually run it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34267/discussion-between-brad-and-joseph-bueno)